# Setting up Virtual Hosts with Apache on Windows 2008 server for multiple sites. Complicated setup, including subversion

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, web-hosting, web

I am setting up apache on my windows 2008 server at my home.  It will serve 2 functions.

1. Subversion hosting to allow me and some others to manage company documents with version control
2. Local website hosting for web development.  Will need to run several websites since I generally work on more then one site at a time.

Heres what I have done so far.

- I set up subversion and apache 2.2 using some walk
  troughs.
- I changed the default port
  to 1337. (im a nerd)
- Using dyndns.com I created a domain to forward to my home ip which is dynamic. ( company.gotdns.org)
- I then went into my DNS for my company.com and added a record to point repo.company.com to company.gotdns.org
- At this point people who need access to my file repository can access by going to repo.company.com/repo which is good so far.

My question comes on the next step, setting up virtual hosts with apache.  Ideally I would like to have my local website be viewable by some others in the company from their homes.  So, say I am working on site1, I would like to have them be able to view this by going site1.roeland.bythepixel.com.  At the same time, I would like to have site10.wouter.bythepixel.com go to his local setup for site10.

What I have done for this:

- I went into my DNS for company.com
  and added a record to point
  roeland.company.com to
  company.gotdns.org (which translates
  to my ip).
- I added code to my httpd-vhosts.conf (listed at bottom)
- I added code to my host file (listed at bottom)

Hah, so of course this doenst work as excepted.. going to site1.roeland.bythepixel.com doesnt bring up my test1 site. **Could anyone point me where I may be going wrong? Thanks!**

**hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       sensenich.roeland.bythepixel.com
::1             localhost
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin roeland@bythepixel.com
    DocumentRoot "F:/Current Projects/sensenich.com"
    ServerName sensenich.roeland.bythepixel.com
    ErrorLog "logs/sensenich.roeland.bythepixel.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/sensenich.roeland.bythepixel.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: +1 - I wish everyone gave this much relevant detail in their questions

Comment: Home-server setup is now off-topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way an expert in this but in my vhosts.conf (on windows) the path to documentroot looks a bit different;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot /HOMEPAGES/duppen.nl  
    ServerName www.duppen.nl  
    ServerAlias duppen.nl  
    ErrorLog logs/duppen.nl-error.log  
    CustomLog logs/duppen.nl-access.log common  
</VirtualHost>
```

then in the httpd.conf the following line is added/modified:
DocumentRoot "W:/HOMEPAGES"

Answer (score 0):

> I went into my DNS for company.com and
>   added a record to point
>   roeland.company.com to
>   company.gotdns.org (which translates
>   to my ip).

You've got that mostly right. If you want `site1.roeland.company.com` to be forwarded, you need to add a wildcard DNS entry, for `*.roeland.company.com` - otherwise, ONLY `roeland.company.com` will resolve.